# List directories (and their subdirectories) with hadoop command line

Tags: hadoop, command-line

is there any way to list **only** directories and their directories recursively  with the hadoop command line?

I was wondering if there is some kind of command similar to the unix command:

> find /tmp -type d -print

Comment: Probably not valid for every user but it might work:  

> hadoop fs -lsr path | cut  -d' ' -f1,19 | grep '^d.*$' "$@" | cut -d' ' -f2

Comment: A better solution: > hadoop fs -lsr $inputPath | awk '{ print $1,$8 }' | grep '^d.*$'

Answer (score 24):

Try this as well: (listing directories from root)

```
hadoop fs -ls -R / | grep "^d"
```

Comment: `hdfs dfs -ls -R / | grep "^d"` Without subdir : `hdfs dfs -ls /`

Comment: only directories and not files, how to?

Comment: @PeterKrauss The `-ls` option lists lines with the permissions as the first field. If the listed item is a directory, they will have some permission like "drw-rw-rw-" (w/ the "d" denoting that the path is that of a directory). Using the `grep "^d"` pipe segment filters for only lines that start (via the caret `^`) with "d".

Answer (score 8):

Try using this command

```
hdfs dfs -ls hdfs:/
```